Could not run jmeter in non GUI
I am trying to run jmeter report in non GUI by command line in my mac ai M2 but it shows error. I couldn't find the solution. The error is in the attachment, my java version is 8 and jmeter is apache-jmeter-5.6.3

I changer java version from java 18 to java 8 but facing same issue

Most probably something is wrong with your JMeter or Java installation, try out the following steps:
unset JVM_ARGS && unset HEAP && unset GC_ALGO && unset JAVA_HOME && unset JRE_HOME
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk i java
sdk i jmeter
$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/jmeter/current/bin/./jmeter.sh -n -t $HOME/.sdkman/candidates/jmeter/current/extras/Test.jmx

I believe it should execute successfully, if it does - review your Java and JMeter installation and any eventual customization for the environment variables from 1st line of the above script
More information:

SDKMAN! Usage
JMeter Installation: How to Get Started
Use environment variables in Terminal on Mac

